# Cmake error on ubuntu14.04

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am trying to build a [project](https://github.com/alexkarargyris/Caffe_OpenCV_Android_App) from git.Getting following error:

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake:95 (message):
  GCC version not detected!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:116 (include)


-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 00 (0)
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/TestBigEndian.cmake:51 (message):
  no suitable type found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:529 (test_big_endian)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Not able to understand the error. Any help appreciated

In the project `3. Build Android OpenCV SDK with extra modules for Android` when I am trying to `sh ./scripts/cmake_android_arm.sh` I am getting the above error.

Comment: Show output of `gcc --version` ?

Comment: @Gluttton gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

Comment: Please, show your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Glutton https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Please, show output of `uname -mpi`.

Comment: @Gluttton x86_64 x86_64 x86_64

Comment: @Glutton problem was with android NDK. I have replaced it. Its working now. Thanks for the time .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the same error:  TestBigEndian: no suitable type found.

However, deleting the CMakeCache.txt file under build_android_arm directory resolved this issue.